# CygWin: grep command shows some "binary file coincidence" message

Tags: cygwin, grep

I have been googling about this, but, maybe due to my spanish version of CygWin/Windows, I have not been able to find a solution.
I have latest (December 2014) **CygWin 32 bits** installed, and it seems there is some problem with its `grep` command.

As you know, CygWin shell can run both Windows and Linux commands, so I am trying to filter the **results of my services** list command, with this results:

```
$ sc query state= all | grep "stopped" -i
Coincidencia en el fichero binario (entrada estándar)
```

I think this message translates to: `Binary file match (standard input)`.

If I try from a **Windows shell** (using only Windows commands):

```
C:\Users\Luis-> sc query state= all | find "stopped" /i 
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
```

... I obtain the correct results.

This is the CygWin embedded grep version:

```
$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.21
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Licencia GPLv3+: GPL de GNU versión 3 o posterior
```

I have found some sort of **workaround** by downloading [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and using its grep 32bit-Windows version:

```
$ PathToUNXUtils="/cygdrive/d/Utilidades/UnxUtils/"

$ "$PathToUNXUtils"grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
Copyright 1988, 1992-1999, 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ sc query state= all | "$PathToUNXUtils"grep "stopped" -i | more.com
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
        ESTADO                       : 1  STOPPED
```

But, well... I think the appropriate way to solve this would be to make the original CygWin's grep version work as it must.

What is going on here? Should I download and compile the latest grep version as last hope?

Comment: Hmm. `sc query state= all | grep "stopped" -i` works as expected here. Lastest version of cygwin (but 64 bit).

Comment: Yep, @DavidPostill, it works for me too sometimes. Seem to be failing only often.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grep a text file which contains some binary data?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9988379)

Comment: You have pointed the problem exactly, @DavidPostill. And, so, the solution. As seen in that thread, there are several ways to solve it. Just adding `--text` to `grep` could enough in some cases, but i should be better to analyze it. You can post it as an answer if you want. If not, I will probably write it later myself. Thanks you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How to grep a text file which contains some binary data?

> **Syntax**
>
> `grep [options] PATTERN [FILE...]`
>
> `grep [options] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]`
>
> **Options**

...

> `-a`
>
> `--text`
>
> Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent
>          to the `--binary-files=text` option.

Using the above option will allow grep to ignore any strange characters that prevent `grep` working as expected.

So the following should work:

```
sc query state= all | grep "stopped" -i --text
```

Or:

```
sc query state= all | grep "stopped" -a -i
```

Source StackOverflow answer [How to grep a text file which contains some binary data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9988534/3536342) by [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) and [grep - Search file(s) for specific text.](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html)

Comment: Can we suppose that some commands like "sc query" drop binary non-printable data when invoked from any CygWin shell? That could explain the issue.